# Edit toolbar icons in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In previous versions of VS I could choose an icon that would display for a toolbar button so that it would take up left space.  I could also draw a custom icon to use for commands.

How do I do that in vs2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an [answer at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242196/visual-studio-2010-adding-commands-to-toolbar)...

> A few of the configuration options
> changes (and some were lost) in VS2010
> (as part of the rework in WPF).
>
> You can do some customisation in the
> Commands tab of the customised
> dialogue (that you get to by right
> clicking on the toolbar). But
> controlling the image is not one of
> them.
>
> **Command Image Changing Extension**
>
> [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150928075859/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/17/command-image-changing-extension.aspx)